# xhtml don't recognize methods declared in managed Bean

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

in my XHTML page I can't call methods declared in managed bean, I'm new to this platform , I'd like that some one clarifies this to me. I'm working on a JSF 2.1 project with JPA on Eclipse Juno 4.2
here's my managed been code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package managedBean;



import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Local;

import model.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import service.EmpFacadeLocal;

/**
 *
 * @author Louuup
 */
@ManagedBean (name= "empbean")
@RequestScoped
@ViewScoped
public class EmpManagedBean {
public Employe emp;
    @EJB
    public EmpFacadeLocal empfacadelocal; 
    public Boolean saisie;
     private List<Employe> emps;
     private String iddd;
     private Employe selectedemp;
     private List<Employe> filteredemps; 
     private Employe[] selectedemps;
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of EmpManagedBean
     */
    public EmpManagedBean() {
        emps = new ArrayList<Employe>();
    }
     @PostConstruct
    public void initEmp(){
        emp = new Employe();
        saisie = false;
         emps = empfacadelocal.getEmpRq("");
    }

    public Employe getEmp() {
        return emp;
    }

    public void setEmp(Employe emp) {
        this.emp = emp;
    }

    public Boolean getSaisie() {
        return saisie;
    }

    public void setSaisie(Boolean saisie) {
        this.saisie = saisie;
    }

    public List<Employe> getEmps() {
        return emps;
    }

    public void setEmps(List<Employe> emps) {
        this.emps = emps;
    }

    public String getIddd() {
        return iddd;
    }

    public void setIddd(String iddd) {
        this.iddd = iddd;
    }

    public Employe getSelectedemp() {
        return selectedemp;
    }

    public void setSelectedemp(Employe selectedemp) {
        this.selectedemp = selectedemp;
    }

    public List<Employe> getFilteredemps() {
        return filteredemps;
    }

    public void setFilteredemps(List<Employe> filteredemps) {
        this.filteredemps = filteredemps;
    }

    public Employe[] getSelectedemps() {
        return selectedemps;
    }

    public void setSelectedemps(Employe[] selectedemps) {
        this.selectedemps = selectedemps;
    }
    public void findEmpaff(){
        //admin = adminfacadelocal.getAdmin(iddd);
        emps = empfacadelocal.getEmpRq("");
    } 
     public void creerEmp(){
         System.out.println("azertre ");
        empfacadelocal.create(emp);
        saisie = true;
    }
}
```

and here is my xhtml page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./../resource/Template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="title">
                <title> Ajout emp</title>
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="page">
                <h:form id="dd">  



                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>  


                    <p:panel header="Fiche Emplyé" >  
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2"  style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Matricule Employé :"/>
                            <p:inputText  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="#{empbean.emp.matEmp}"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Nom Employé :"/>
                            <p:inputText  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="#{empbean.emp.nomEmp}"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Prénom Employé :"/>
                            <p:inputText  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="#{empbean.emp.prenomEmp}"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Date de naissance Employé :"/>
                            <p:calendar disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" locale="pt" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" id="pttCal" value="#{empbean.emp.dateNaisEmp}"/>  
                            <h:outputLabel value="Adresse Employé :"/>
                            <p:inputText  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="#{empbean.emp.adressEmp}"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="N° téléph Employé :"/>
                            <p:inputText  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="#{emp.emp.numTelfEmp}"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="E-mail Employé :"/>
                            <p:inputText  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="#{empbean.emp.emailEmp}"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="N° compte Employé :"/>
                            <p:inputText  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="#{empbean.emp.numCompteEmp}"/>

                            <p:selectOneMenu disabled="#{empManagedBean.saisie}" value="#{empbean.emp.fonctionEmp}">  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Jardinier" itemValue="Jardinier" />    
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Agent d'hygiene" itemValue="Agent d'hygiene" /> 
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Agent de sécurité" itemValue="Agent de sécurité" />    
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Magasinier" itemValue="Magasinier" /> 
                            </p:selectOneMenu> 






                        </h:panelGrid><br/>
                        <p:commandButton  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="Valider" update="dd" style="margin-left: 250px;"  actionListener="#{empbean.   }"/>



                    </p:panel> 

                </h:form>  
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want call "creerEmp" method in command button's actionlistener like this #{empbean.creerEmp()} but I can't do this , please someone help me

Comment: Please state the exact warning/error/exception message which you faced instead of an unhelpful "I can't do this" statement. The exact warning/error/exception message is usually already the whole answer at its own. If you're unable to decipher it, just share it with us, we usually can translate it for you in layman's terms.

Comment: You are using `RequestScoped` and `ViewScoped` as scopes of your `empbean`.

Answer (score 0):

A method for an actionlistener needs to have an ActionEvent parameter. But I think what you want is a normal action which should be fine like this:

```
<p:commandButton  disabled="#{empbean.saisie}" value="Valider" 
    update="dd" style="margin-left: 250px;"  action="#{empbean.creerEmp}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work with `#{empbean.creerEmp}` . ActionEvent parameter is not neccesary.

You should try without composition component firstly to see if your ActionListener method works. Besides I think that You're using composition component incorrectly.